# Drawing lines between points recorded through GPS device in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have collected data (GPS Coordinates) for an 11 KV Distribution line (pole to pole GPS coordinates) through a GPS device. The distribution line consists of different kind of conductors (i.e. ACSR Dog conductor, ACSR Rabbit Conductor between different points) and electrical transformer of difference rating (i.e. 50 KVA, 100 KVA, 200 KVA). The GPS points have unique IDs. I have also Data on paper which specifies the location of transformers, S/E, kind of conductor between different points.
My problem is how to draw a line between these GPS points with different line segments specifying kind of conductor (ACSR DOG, ACSR RAB between different points) from the attribute table. Also I want to give specific symbols for transformers located at different GPS points.

[image: Example of data on paper]

i am using ArcMap. i have tried points to line which simply connects all the points. i need segments with different properties. I am new to ArcGis. I need the concept to do the work i have mentioned in question

Comment: Make XY event layer then https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-lines-from-points.htm

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What have you tried?

Comment: i am using ArcMap. i have tried points to line which simply connects all the points. i need segments with different properties. I am new to ArcGis. I need the concept to do the work i have mentioned in question.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.